# questions regarding tokenisation in c

Tags: c

I am writing a tokenisation program. I want to get input from a file, then store it in an input pointer. I am using the strtok function but when I print my tokens[i] I get NULL.

```
 int tokenise(char *input, int file_output)
 {
     int i = 0;
     char *tokens[100];
     for(i=0 ;i<=20;i++)
     {
         tokens[i]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
     }

     char delim[] = " ,.;@/";
     printf("\n -------------  buffer data is %s",input);
     tokens[i] = strtok(input , delim);
     printf("tokens are %s",*tokens[0]);
     int j=0;

     while(NULL != tokens[i])
     {
         i++;
         tokens[i] = strtok(NULL,delim);
     }

     for(j = i; j <= 0; j--)
     {
         write(file_output,tokens[i],strlen(tokens[i]));
     }
     for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
     {
         printf("%s \n",*tokens[i]);
     }
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The C++ tag is debatable since this is clearly C but why did you tag Java!?!?

Comment: `for(j=i; j<=0;j--)` : `j=i` change to `j=i-1` because last `tokens[i]` is `NULL`.

Comment: You need to pass `NULL` into `strtok()` as well, after the first call: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you allocate memory and write pointers to the first 21 elements of `tokens[]`. At the end of that loop, `i` is 21. You then parse the input string using `strtok()`, storing its results in continuing array elements, from `tokens[21]`. So two of your loops need rewriting:

```
for(j=21; j<i; j++)
    write(file_output,tokens[j],strlen(tokens[j]));

for(j=21; j<i; j++)
    printf("%s \n",*tokens[j]);
```

But it would be better if you removed the first loop that allocates unnecessary memory. `strtok()` returns pointers to the original string, which it breaks into pieces by inserting `'\0'` terminators, so you only need to store the pointers in the array `tokens[]`.